# react-router-dom+antD/ How to set a Nav Element Active as per the current route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, antd

I Created the following NavBar

```
  import React,{Component} from "react";

  import { Layout, Menu ,Icon} from 'antd';
  import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
  const { Header } = Layout;
  const SubMenu = Menu.SubMenu;


 class NavBar extends Component {

constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={
  current: '1'
 }

this.handleMenuClick=this.handleMenuClick.bind(this);
}

  handleMenuClick(e){
    this.setState({
    current : e.key  
  })
}

 render(){
   return(
    <Layout className="layout">
      <Header>
        <div className="logo" />
        <Menu
          theme="light"
          mode="horizontal"
          style={{ lineHeight: '64px' }}
          selectedKeys={[this.state.current]}
          onClick={this.handleMenuClick}
        >
          <Menu.Item key="1"><NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink></Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="2"><NavLink to="/about">About Us</NavLink></Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="3"><NavLink to="/contact">Contact Us</NavLink></Menu.Item>

         <SubMenu key="4" title={<span><Icon type="setting" />Account</span>}>
              <Menu.Item key="setting:1"><NavLink to="/login">Sign In</NavLink></Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item key="setting:2"><NavLink to="/register">Register</NavLink></Menu.Item>
          </SubMenu>

        </Menu>
      </Header>
   </Layout>
       );
   }
}

 export default NavBar;
```

and its active state works fine while navigating from one state to another.But as soon as I hit the refresh button ,despite of what route it is currently on , It always sets the Home Nav Active. How can I set the nav element active dynamically, even if page gets refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the

`current: '1'`

Instead you should set the key based on the menu selected, If you have different endpoints for urls, you can get the url and based on the url you can modify the `current` variable.

If you don't have different url for different menu, you can save the current state using localstorage and can get the state from localstore agaain